# How can I use my NextJS application with CloudFlare or CloudFront CDN?

Tags: caching, next.js, amazon-cloudfront, cloudflare, cdn

I have an e-commerce application that I developed with NextJS 13 App Directory and I host it on my own server.
Nextjs default cache system works fine, but the cache is reset every time I deploy. I do not have content that is always updated, but I would like to serve my content via CloudFlare or CloudFront CDN.
Some parts of my application are static and some parts are dynamic. For example, I want dynamic pages such as user profile and shopping cart to run directly on the server without a CDN, but I want product pages, about us, contact pages to run static via CDN.

In order for CloudFlare cache to work, "Cache-Control" needs to be set, but you cannot do this with the NextJS 13 App directory.

In short;

Dynamic pages directly from the server without CDN,
I want to offer static pages to my customers via CDN.

Thanks for your help!

I tried to set cache-control on Nextjs but it didn't work.
I have defined page-based Cache Control from the CloudFlare domain panel -> Cache Rules field, but I want to set which pages will be static and which pages will be dynamic, not through CloudFlare, but through NextJS.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the "dynamic" options
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config#dynamic ?

so i think you can just add

```
export const dynamic = 'force-static'
```

to the page / layout you want to cache